# Higher Level API For Sensor Values Pitch And Roll

Tags: android, sensors, device-orientation, pitch

I am implementing my own camera Activity.
To rotate the captured image I need to know the orientation at the time of shooting.
Is there a higher level API for the sensor values pitch and roll that tells me my device is oriented in:
top-down - holding the phone normal, portrait
down-top
right-left - landscape the top of the phone is on the right side
left-right - landscape the top of the phone is on the left side

Or is there any other way to geht it directly from the system?

Comment: what do you mean by top-down,.. left-right?

Comment: You could just write a function that checks this and call it whenever you need. Also, you should accept answers if you want people to answer your questions. Take a look at your old answers and accept the best ones. The button is at the answers rating.

Comment: thanks for that advise, I have a look at that feature

Answer (score 1):

sadly ,cameras work in a weird way on android when they are not in landscape mode (which is the "natural" orientation for camera on android) .

best thing to do is set the activity to be in landscape mode , and add the onConfigurationChanged event (and add the android:configChanges="orientation" into the manifest) in order to get the current orientation .

when capturing the image, check the orientation and act according to whatever logic you wish to have.

Comment: Good point. I didn't know that something like the onConfigurationChanged event exists. I tried it out and it can only tell me if I am in portrait or landscape mode. The camera sensor has one direction but landscape can have two, when I tillt the camera to the right or left. I need a way to determine how I have to rotate the outcome.

Comment: if you target 2.2+ , you might have luck with this :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29

Comment: Another nice pice of API I havn't heard of ;) I tried it but it shows me always 0 degrees. int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation(); Maybee it is because I set the orientation fixed in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved my problem to a certain point so that it works for me and I left out the down-top recognition.

```
public class DeviceOrientation {

public static final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 0;
public static final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_REVERSE = 1;
public static final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2;
public static final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE = 3;

int smoothness = 1;
public float averagePitch = 0;
public float averageRoll = 0;
public int orientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

private float[] pitches;
private float[] rolls;

public DeviceOrientation(int smoothness) {
    this.smoothness = smoothness;

    pitches = new float[smoothness];
    rolls = new float[smoothness];
}

public void addSensorEvent(SensorEvent event) {
    azimuth = event.values[0];

    averagePitch = addValue(event.values[1], pitches);
    averageRoll = addValue(event.values[2], rolls);

    orientation = calculateOrientation();
}

private float addValue(float value, float[] values) {
    float average = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<smoothness; i++) {
        values[i-1] = values[i];
        average += values[i];
    }
    values[smoothness-1] = value;
    average = (average + value)/smoothness;

    return average;
}

/** handles all 4 possible positions perfectly */
private int calculateOrientation() {
    // finding local orientation dip
    if (((orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE)
            && (averageRoll > -30 && averageRoll < 30))) {
        if (averagePitch > 0)
            return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE;
        else
            return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    } else {
        // divides between all orientations
        if (Math.abs(averagePitch) >= 30) {
            if (averagePitch > 0)
                return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE;
            else
                return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        } else {
                if (averageRoll > 0) {
                    return ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_REVERSE;
                } else {
                    return ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:
If I am in portrait-mode and tillt the mobil forward until it is in a horizontal position it would switch to landscape due to the rest of the code.
Therefore I check if it is in portrait and make the conditions hard to leafe this mode.
This is what I ment with the local dip.
The rest just divides into all 3 directions.

One thing is bad. If the device is in landscape_x and get tillt some degrees backwards, the pich jumps from ~2 to ~175. At that point my code is fliping inbetween landscape and portrait.

The smoothness will smooth the value for the sensor data by combining the last n values and calculating the average. It isn't realy necesary.

I hope this will help others. If you can improve the code further, please let me know.

Comment: The code is updated. The full project to play with it is on my google drive. [SensorDemo.rar](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4dC-qLD0ltec3BteVNBTDB2OFU)

Comment: I left out the down-top orientation what probably no one realy needs and if you tillt your device to landscape and tillt it a little bit to you so that the camera looks ~3-10 degrees up the orientation toggles between landscape and portrait.

Comment: what's down-top orientation? is it portrait-reversed?

Comment: It is the oposite to the normal portrait (top-down). When your device is turned 180 degrees.

Comment: @strangeoptics I've edited the code to handle the last position (reverse portrait) in case someone needs it as I was, & thanks for the calculation itself it helped me a lot :)